# What are the sklearn tree_.value for nodes (not leaves)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

```
from sklearn import tree
import graphviz
import shap

X,y = shap.datasets.boston()

clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2).fit(X, y)
```

gives us the following tree:

[image]

The values are confusing to me, I understand that the values at leaves are the predictions once that leaf is reached. However what do the values at nodes represent?

I found a few SO posts/documentation for Classification but not for regression.

EDIT: Thinking about if further I see that they're most likely just the values of those bins if the tree was cut short. Not sure why exactly they're used in SHAP though.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus in one node, for example:

[image]

- `X12<= 14.4` refers to the next split you will apply to your data. In
  this case you will use the feature X 12.
- `Samples= 430`, refers to all training samples that are in this node.
  Check that the root node is 506 (which is the sum of his son nodes
  (430+76))
- If we make a prediction at this internal node, we will predict that
  the values is `value=19.934` and we will be committing an `mse= 40.273`, which refers to the error.

Obviously, when we are splitting data with more nodes, we are reducing the number of `samples` and of course the `mse`, since we are narrowing down. The value vary since we are being more precis.

About `shap`, you are only using this library to import the dataset, nothing more. You could have imported the data without using the `shap` library. There are different ways to import Boston data, for example using Sklearn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
```

Anyway, you should check if it's the exact dataset (e.g., one data set have more samples).